# Receivng intent broadcasts when application is shutdown

Tags: android, android-intent, android-c2dm, broadcast

I'm using C2DM the first time and I'm looking for a general advice how I can achieve the following:
Upon receiving a C2DM messages I decide:
 - if the application is upon the current activity will display an "alert popup".
 - if the application is not open I'd like to send a message to the notification bar (similar to new emails, sms, twitter etc.)

We have a `GlobalBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` which implements  `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`. This is the *only* receiver registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
So basically all our broadcasts are piped through this receiver and the first scenario is no problem.

However I'm, wondering how to tackle the second problem. How can I make sure I receive a C2DM.RECEIVE broadcast even when my application is closed and then: how can I notify the user about the incoming data?

I'm super confident there are already a lot of solutions out there but since I couldn't find them I think I'm just missing something of the bigger picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make sure I receive a C2DM.RECEIVE broadcast even when my application is closed

Have your receiver registered in the manifest, [per the C2DM documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest).

> then: how can I notify the user about the incoming data?

Raise a `Notification`.

Since your receiver will not necessarily know if there is an activity of yours in the foreground, the best solution is to send your own broadcast `Intent`, but one that is ordered. Have the activity register a high-priority `BroadcastReceiver` for your own broadcast, and have another manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` implement a normal-priority `BroadcastReceiver` for your own broadcast. If the activity gets the broadcast, it displays your popup (ick) and aborts the broadcast. If your "backstop" `BroadcastReceiver` gets the broadcast, it displays a `Notification`. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) with a bit more detail on this pattern, and [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered) demonstrating this use of ordered broadcasts.

Comment: Could you elaborate this part a little bit more detailed please? "Have the activity register a high-priority BroadcastReceiver for your own broadcast, and have another manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver implement a normal-priority BroadcastReceiver for your own broadcast." Also I'll check this tomorrow. I need my quiet time to test all of this :)

Comment: @yoshi: I specifically provided hyperlinks to a blog post and a sample project to provide more details.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Just after receiving your answer I had a little bit of drama with the whole c2dm system. I like the pattern you described in the article. Really neat to use ordered broadcasts in that way. Anyway after reading I realised actually all the work was already done. I just didn't understood that `BroadcastReceiver`s registered in the manifest will be execute even with no activity running. Sweet :)